# redshift in astrophysical plots

Tags: astrophysics, redshift

Why do astrophysicists often use redshift in plots? Why it is important to know how an astrophysical object evolves in function of redshift? I was seeing an "cosmological time per redshift galaxies formation plot" and thinking why redshift and not, who knows, density?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it needs more focus. Perhaps ask these "sub-questions" in new ones?

Answer (score 3):

Redshifts are plotted because usually that is all that can be *measured*.

Other quantities could be plotted, but since these are *inferred* from the redshift itself (e.g. density would just mean plotting $(1+z)^3$), or would need to assume particular cosmological models or parameters (e.g. if you plotted look-back time), then it makes sense to stick with plotting the observed data.